Kotlin coroutines supervisorscope, child job cancels all sibling jobs, why?
In kotlin coroutines I studied supervisorscope won't cancel the sibling jobs if one of the job get cancelled or thrown exception in it. In IntelliJ it works good, but in Android Project it throws the exception and crashes the app.
suspend fun asyncJobLaunchWithTryCatchSample() {
    supervisorScope {

        val nameJob = launch {
            Log.i(TAG, "asyncLaunchWithTryCatchSample: nameJob Started")
            val name = getName()//fake api call with delay of 1 second
            Log.i(TAG, "asyncLaunchWithTryCatchSample: nameJob completed $name")
        }

        val ageJob1 = launch {
            Log.i(TAG, "asyncLaunchWithTryCatchSample: ageJob1 Started")
            throw Exception("dsadasd")
        }

        val ageJob2 = launch {//fake api call with delay of 1 second
            Log.i(TAG, "asyncLaunchWithTryCatchSample: ageJob2 Started")
            val age = getAgeNull()
            Log.i(TAG, "asyncLaunchWithTryCatchSample: ageJob2 Completed $age")
        }

        joinAll(nameJob,ageJob1,ageJob2)
        Log.i(TAG, "asyncJobLaunchWithTryCatchSample: completed")

    }
}

I called this function using compose button click with a coroutine scope.

Your child coroutines are not cancelled - they crash. And when they do so they have to handle it as supervisor scope does not consume failure of its children.
So you end up with wild uncaught exception that ends up being propagated "out" of supervisor scope and most likely end up directly in CoroutineExceptionHandler that exists in the dispatcher.
And if that dispatcher is Main (which it probably is as you call this function from button) it means app crash.

I studied that the child job cancellation won't cancel the other siblings, is that wrong?
I tried it in kotlin project in IntelliJ using runBlocking in main function it worked good, May I know what does it works fine?
And I used IO Dispatchers on button click

At least on kotlin playground crashing such child coroutines does nothing beside printing exception in the output. So it does come down to how exception is propagated and what exception handler ends up consuming it - default handlers are different on raw jvm environment and android.
